# Error with the ScriptingBridge email message forwarding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email, scripting-bridge

I'm going to develope own email- plugin included to my application. At the moment I have a problem with the email forwarding to the third user. There is the code snippet:

EmailApplication.h

`MailApplication *mail;`

`@property(nonatomic, retain) MailApplication *mail;`

EmailApplication.m

`@synthesize mail`

`-(void)loadAllEmails{`

```
self.mail = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@”com.apple.Mail”];
```

`}`

`-(void)acceptMessageForwarding:(MailMessage *)message To:(NSString *)address{`

```
message.readStatus = YES;

MailOutgoingMessage *forwardMessage = [message forwardOpeningWindow:NO];

[[mail outgoingMessages] addObject: forwardMessage];

MailToRecipient *theRecipient = ...

...
```

`}`

The problem is that every time when I'm trying to add forwardMessage to the outgoingMessages- array, application crashes with the output: **-[SBElementArray addObject:]: can't add an object that already exists.**
(MailMessage *)message is ok so the problem is in somewhere else. I have noticed that the same error comes with the email sending script when allocating the new MailOutgoingMessage and changing the classForScriptingClass text from the outgoing message to the another.
Do I need some another parameters? Or do I have to do forwarding by another way?